# How to inherit dependency version from required BOM POM in maven spring boot project?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new to spring boot world and encountered with an issue. I have a requirement of using mssql in my project which I am default getting as a dependency from **spring-boot-starter-parent** but the catch is the version which is getting inherited is what i do not want.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This will give me mssql version mssql-jdbc : 6.1.0.jre7 (Which i do not want)

My organization has a dedicated BOM POM created for all the common components used in all the projects which includes mssql latest version. **mssql-jdbc :8.4.1.jre8**

I have declare this BOM POM under **dependencyManagement** tag.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
     <grpId></grpId>
     <artifactiID></>
     <version/>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now my POM is only taking mssql version from **spring boot parent** (Which is obvious as per the tree hierarchy) but i want to use version from BOM POM.

I also don't want to hardcode the mssql version in my pom dependency like

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>It should take from the BOM POM declared in dependency management</version>
```

So that whenever a new version got updated in my BOM POM, it should reflect directly in my application POM file.

my question can be repetitive or easy to figure out but as i am new to the spring world, Your help will be helpful for sure.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: First should start with recent Spring Boot version which is 2.4.3 and not 1.X anymore (long EoL)... second if you use spring boot you should learn to use the versions which are offered by spring boot parents/BOM's...

Comment: You can override the version of any dependency provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: @khmarbaise You are correct that we should use latest version only but this is something which is company mandate to use.

Comment: @akuma8 how to override ? if i am not specifying version then by default it it using spring boot starter version.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

Parent POM versions are stronger than BOM versions.

You need to add the version explicitly in your POM and change it manually when the BOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

To override the version of a dependency you have to find how it was defined in the parent POM. Example in your case, if you look at the Spring Boot parent POM, in the `<properties>` section, you should see something like:

```
<mssql.version>Y.XX</mssql.version> <!-- please note that I am not really sure about the property name but I am 100% that the version is defined as a property-->
```

Then  copy-paste that property in the `<properties>` section of your POM and set the version you want.